# BufferedReader not returning

Tags: java, command-line, stream, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am using Java to run a program and reading the program's text output into a buffered reader. I then want to print out the results by doing this:

```
    while((line=input.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

For some reason, when doing this the readLine() method does not return at all about halfway through the text, and the program waits indefinitely. Yet when running this program from the command line directly, its output is exactly as expected, just 100 lines or so of simple text. What could cause readLine() to not return halfway through reading simple text?

Comment: How this question is related to _java-stream_ or _stream_?

Comment: because the bufferedReader class is just an encapsulation of a stream

Comment: Need a reproducible example

Comment: have you tried using scanner instead?

Comment: @nicomp I agree but not sure how I can provide one without giving the entire program I am running

Comment: Yes scanner gives the same results

Comment: Can you show the whole method - where you open the buffered input reader, try/catch, close the file. So far, there is no mistake in the snippet that you have providrd.

Comment: @chessprogrammer The point of the exercise is to reduce your program to the smallest footprint that still produces the error. You have to put in the time.

Comment: When you’re reading a “program's text output”, the `readLine()` may block until either, the program writes another line or the program closes the stream which usually only happens when the program exits. A typical problem arises when the program waits for input from your side, then you have a deadlock.

Comment: when you say, you used java to run another program, do you mean Runtime.exec kind of execution?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: May be program, that you are executing, writes output to a buffer and flushes on some signal. This works for direct command line execution but for java wrapped execution somehow the output is never flushed. That's why you see partial result. Some output is flushed when buffer is full but the remaining is never flushed. Does the program take any input or inputstream? can you try childProcess.getOutputStream().close(); This will send EOF to the program.

Comment: If exactly this code blocks midway, then the `input` has an issue. A data error (wrong encoding, like expecting UTF-8) is unlikely to cause blocking. A remote connection with timeout might be the case.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if nothing has been written to the stream.
You may often encounter the situation in which readLine() hangs is when you invoke a process that is supposed to write errors to stderr. When the process finishes you may try to read all the errors by doing:

```
BufferedReader brCleanUp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine()) != null) {
     //process the error line
}
brCleanUp.close();
```

But if nothing at all was written to stderr, the above readLine() would hang as you described.

The way to avoid it is to check if there is any point of reading the stream (I don't know if it's a bug or not, but this worked for me:)

```
boolean available = stderr.available() >= 1;
if (available) {
    BufferedReader brCleanUp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
    for( ; available && (line = brCleanUp.readLine()) != null; 
            available = stderr.available() >= 1) {
        System.out.println ("[Stderr] " + line);
    }
    brCleanUp.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the text document into **UTF-8** like this, then use **Scanner**.

```
// specify file path
String filePath = "C:/path/path/file-location/file.txt";
// make a scanner with the UTF-8 param
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath),"UTF-8");
// loop through text 
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
   System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

There are actually a few ways to encode text like this, but the importance lies within the text encoding itself. Once you have the document in the correct format, the objects and classes you chose to read input are at your own discretion.

Answer (score 1):

> What could cause readLine() to not return halfway through reading simple text?

If you are reading from a file in a file system, this is possibly due to a problem with the file system; e.g. a remote file server is not responding.

If you are reading from a socket, either the remote server hasn't (yet) written / flushed the data you are trying to read, or a network problem is stopping the data from getting through.

If you are reading from a pipe (e.g. the output of another program), then the other program hasn't written / flushed the data you are trying to read.

(Another cases are reading from a "device file" or a file in the "/proc" file system, or a loopback file system.  In these cases, the possible causes are difficult to enumerate.)